# I am trying to bootstrap angularjs and Requirejs,but I always end up with dependency injection error

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, requirejs, single-page-application

Actually I have been trying to develop a single page application using requirejs and angularjs. I have loaded all files that are necessary,while running the app without any other angular apps and without dependencies everything works fine,but when I call the requirejs definedjs files to load within the define() in app.js the application throws the following error,

> [$injector:nomod] Module 'app' is not available! You either
>   misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a
>   module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second
>   argument.

**Here is my html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <base href="/">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Advances in Central Science</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="assets/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <!-- Requirejs -->
    <script data-main="client/js/main" src="client/bower_libs/requirejs/require.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
        <h1>{{message}}</h1>
        <button class="btn btn-success">Success</button>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**My Requirejs**

```
// requirejs

require.config({
    baseUrl: '/',
    paths: {

        // Aliases and paths of modules
        'angular': 'client/bower_libs/angular/angular',
        'uiRouter': 'client/bower_libs/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min',
        'bootstrap': 'client/bower_libs/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min',
        'jquery': 'client/bower_libs/jquery/dist/jquery.min',


        // paths
        'app': 'client/js/app',
        'includesjs': 'client/js/includesjs',
        'includescss': 'client/js/includescss',
        'modules': 'client/js/controllers/main'
    },
    map: {

        // Maps
        '*': {

            'css': 'client/bower_libs/require-css/css.min.js'
        }
    },
    shim: {
        // Modules and their dependent modules
        'angular': { exports: 'angular' },
        'uiRouter': { deps: ['angular'] },
        'bootstrap': { deps: ['jquery'] }

    },
    // kick start application
    deps: ['client/js/initialize']


});
```

**Initialize.js**

```
define(['app', 'includesjs'], function() {

    return true;
})
```

**app.js(I cant get what I am doing wrong here)**

```
=========working
    define(['angular'], function(angular) {

    var app = angular.module('app', []);

    return app;

=========not Working
   define(['angular','uiRouter'], function(angular) {

    var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router']);

    return app;

});
```

**includes.js**

```
define([
    'modules/mainCtrl'

], function() {

    return true;
});
```

**mainController.js**

```
define(['app'], function(app) {
    app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.message = "Hello,the page works like a charm";
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you only need to define the `uiRouter` while defining the angular.

Try something like this.

```
define(['angular'], function(angular) {

var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router']);

return app;
```

Its because you only need to define the dependencies on module level. Not on angular framework level. Hope that solves your issue

Comment: thanks for your reply, I did the same but without including the js,how can i pass the dependency

Comment: and where exactly are you saying , in controller or app.js

Comment: I am saying in app.js

Comment: yeah,you can see that I already have that , but I cannot directly inject without defining js file